# PowerBI - 2 tables, with one measure and filter

Tags: powerbi

i have 2 tables:

1. Invite, contains original automatic invites
2. Response, actual responses, however including manual uploads. To differentiate between 2 we have column DataEntry - Automatic or Manual

I need a measure that will work for the following logic

I have a slicer/filter - DataEntry - Automatic or Manual
The measure must do the following

1. If Filter = Automatic Measure will show me the Count of lines in the table Invite
2. If Filter = Manual Measure will show me the Count of lines in table Response, where DataEntry=Manual
3. If Filter = All or nothing, then 1+2

---

I have this formula, but somehow it not working

Count =

var ManualCount = CALCULATE (count(Response[field]), Response[DataEntry]="Manual")
var Invitations = CALCULATE (count(Invite[field]))

var Selections = CONCATENATEX (VALUES (Response[DataEntry]),Response[DataEntry],",")

var isManual = CONTAINSSTRING(Selections,"Manual")
var isAutomated = CONTAINSSTRING(Selections,"Automated")

Var state = If (AND(isManual, NOT isAutomated),1, (If ( AND(not isManual, isAutomated), 2, 3)))

var result = SWITCH(State, 1, ManualCount, 2, Invitations, 3, ManualCount+Invitations, ManualCount+Invitations)

Return result

Comment: Problem solved, somehow measure was created as Calc Column instead of Measure